# How do we get more users to contribute to beta?

Tags: discussion

If you look through the list of users and their ratings on DSP.SE, there aren't many participants. Is there a way to send everyone "a friendly reminder" that the web site is still here and is in need of active users?

Also, I know that while some of us are good at answering signals related questions, none of us should hesitate to ask questions, too. If you think of a good question (doesn't matter if you know the answer already), you should post it. Even it's just going to be between the 8 of us or so, we have to keep the site going.

Answer (score 4):

I think the "simple" answer would be make it public instead of private...